# How can you deny access to MarkLogic 10 declareUpdate(); to certain users in certain environments?

Tags: permissions, marklogic

We are using MarkLogic 10 and are trying to block `declareUpdate();` to certain users in certain environments?

I'm assuming that we just need to remove a privilege from those user's roles but not sure which all privileges we would to remove access to `declareUpdate()` to trigger an error anytime they attempted to execute it.

Comment: Do the users need to install code on the server at all?

Could the users send query requests to the /v1/rows endpoint to get the data that they need?